# Cant seem to set global vars correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to store a token into a global var. When the alert is run it says null, but if I put 2 alerts one after the other the 1st shows null but the second shows the token.

Its like the token is not being set because the 1st alert is run before the ajax request has finished.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
var csrf_token = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
    get_csrf_token();
    alert('token 1 '+csrf_token);
    alert('token 2 '+csrf_token);
});

function get_csrf_token()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://buscore/index.php/includes/csrf_token/",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp, status) {
            if (resp.status != 'success')
            {
                alert('Error - Update CSRF Token\n\n' + resp.status);
                return;
            }

            csrf_token = resp.csrf_token;
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks

**UPDATED**

Ok thanks for your help everyone but still dont see how this would work. I use get_csrf_token() like jqgrid to send the token with the request like below. So how do I pass the token to and have it working?

```
beforeRequest: function (){
        get_csrf_token()
        //alert(csrf_token);
        $("#customer_grid").setPostDataItem('<?php echo $csrf_token_name; ?>', csrf_token);
    }
```

Comment: Guess it's working .. first `alert(resp.csrf_token)` to make sure.

Comment: You should use firebug to see if it's making the ajax call twice, failing the first time. If it is you can expand and see what the error was. That will assist in troubleshooting the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The A in AJAX stands for 'asynchronous'. While you are busy clicking on the first alert, the AJAX request is going through and the value is filled. You will need to place all code that needs the variable csrf_token into your callback function. Alternatively, you can look into using jQuery 1.5 or above (if you aren't already). It has so-called [Deferred Objects](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/)

> This API allows you to work with return values that may not be immediately present (such as the return result from an asynchronous Ajax request).

You can also set the `async` value on your post request to`false`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "http://buscore/index.php/includes/csrf_token/",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(resp, status) {
        if (resp.status != 'success')
        {
            alert('Error - Update CSRF Token\n\n' + resp.status);
            return;
        }

        csrf_token = resp.csrf_token;
    }
});
```

This will make the browser wait for the response before proceeding with the rest of your code. I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, but it should work.

Comment: That does the job?! The success function is returning to nowhere. The get_csrf_token function isn't returning anything. `token` is just going to be undefined.

Comment: @David Dorward: Aaargh, yeah, I see. I suppose the OP meant the "async: false" one. I'll delete the one that won't work.

Answer (score 5):

The success callback function runs when the HTTP response arrives.

In your test, the response is arriving between the time that the first alert is displayed and the time you click the button to let the script continue.

Do whatever you need to do with the data in the callback, not as the statement after the one where you initiate the Ajax request.

Example as requested by comment:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    get_csrf_token();
});

function get_csrf_token()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://buscore/index.php/includes/csrf_token/",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp, status) {
            if (resp.status != 'success')
            {
                alert('Error - Update CSRF Token\n\n' + resp.status);
                return;
            }

            alert('token 1 '+csrf_token);
            alert('token 2 '+csrf_token);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Dorward - New to javascript any examples

Comment: Dorward - csrf_token does not get set at all and I only used alert to see if csrf_token was set. Thanks anyways

Comment: It doesn't matter if you want to alert it or do something else with it. The point is that you do it in the callback.

Comment: Dorward - I have updated my 1st post to better explain what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

The AJAX request is async. That means the script doesn't wait for it to finish. When the first alert fires the token is not set. But until you hit OK it has time to load and the token will be set.

Here's the order of the operations:

1. call `get_csrf_token`
2. make token request
3. show alert 1
4. finish request and set `csrf_token`
5. client hits OK on the first alert
6. show alert 2 (the token variable was set at 4.)